# What does each column of objdump's Symbol table mean?

Tags: objdump

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000  w      *UND*  0000000000000000              __gmon_start__
```

I've `man objdump` but there's no such info.

Anyone know what the **5** columns mean?

Answer (score 110):

COLUMN ONE: the symbol's value

COLUMN TWO: a set of characters and spaces indicating the flag bits that are set on the symbol. There are seven groupings which are listed below:

group one: (l,g,,!) local, global, neither, both.

group two: (w,) weak or strong symbol.

group three: (C,) symbol denotes a constructor or an ordinary symbol.

group four: (W,) symbol is warning or normal symbol.

group five: (I,) indirect reference to another symbol or normal symbol.

group six: (d,D,) debugging symbol, dynamic symbol or normal symbol.

group seven: (F,f,O,) symbol is the name of function, file, object or normal symbol.

COLUMN THREE: the section in which the symbol lives, *ABS* means not associated with a certain section

COLUMN FOUR: the symbol's size or alignment.

COLUMN FIVE: the symbol's name.

If you want additional information try you man  page ;-) or the following links: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man1/objdump.1.html and https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html

Comment: Just wondering, for the COLUMN FOUR, what is the size usually expressed as? Are we looking at bytes or bits?

Comment: @Zhouster, In order to accelerate the speed of symbol table loading, I think it is 4-bytes alignment for 32-bits system.

Comment: @Zhouster. Bytes, always bytes.

Comment: Links in answer now redirect to https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man1/objdump.1.html and https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html - I'll edit to update them later, but the edit queue is full right now.

Comment: Re my above comment - the queue's not full so I've just submitted that edit.

Answer (score 10):

Since none of the previous answers seem to be correct, here's what you are actually looking for:

Here's a snippet from this [link](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html) that might help:

"The other common output format, usually seen with ELF based files, looks like this:

```
      00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
      00000000 g       .text  00000000 fred
```

Here the first number is the symbol's value (sometimes refered to as its address). The next field is actually a set of characters and spaces indicating the flag bits that are set on the symbol. These characters are described below. Next is the section with which the symbol is associated or *ABS* if the section is absolute (ie not connected with any section), or *UND* if the section is referenced in the file being dumped, but not defined there.

After the section name comes another field, a number, which for common symbols is the alignment and for other symbol is the size. Finally the symbol's name is displayed."

Answer (score 7):

**objdump -t** prints the symbol table entries of the file.
The output is similar to the information provided by the **nm** program.

There are ***7 columns*** in the output:

- value
- class
- type
- size
- line
- section
- symbol-name

(some columns may be empty for some entries)

**objdump** prints the **symbol-name** in **left-most column**.
**nm** prints the **symbol-name** in the **right-most column**.

Comment: "(some columns may be empty for some entries)" That sucks HARD. How did they imagine one could easily parse the symbol table if one can't even be sure if a certain column even has a value, and there is no delimiter character either? :-((

Comment: Found a way, using this reqex: ^((?xi)[a-f0-9]+)\s+([lgu\!])([w ])([C ])([W ])([Ii ])([dD ])([FfO ])\s+(\S+)\s+((?xi)[a-f0-9]+)\s+(\S+)$

Answer (score 4):

http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/compilecycle.html#runtime

```
$ nm --format sysv simple   # system V format is easier to read than bsd format which is the default

Name                  Value   Class        Type         Size     Line  Section

...
foo                 |080484e6|   T  |              FUNC|0000000c|     |.text
```

Comment: What has `nm` to do with `objdump`?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard,what does Class `w` stand for?

Comment: @Je sorry I don't know, just edited the answer so it has better formatting.

Comment: I found here what I was looking for here, useful answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

From description of option *-t* in [man pages of objdump from man7.org](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html), the format is explained as follows:

> The other common output format, usually seen with ELF based files, looks like this:

```
              00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
              00000000 g       .text  00000000 fred
```

> - Here the first number is the symbol's value (sometimes refered to as its address).
> - The next field is actually a set of characters and spaces indicating the flag bits that are set on the symbol.These characters are described below.
> - Next is the section with which the symbol is associated or *ABS* if the section is absolute (ie not connected with any section), or *UND* if the section is referenced in the file being dumped, but not defined there.
> - After the section name comes another field, a number, which for common symbols is the alignment and for other symbol is the size. Finally the symbol's name is displayed.

You can visit above site for a more detail description.